# Error Handling in REST API: Best Practice

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am trying to develop a rest api that basically return information about country. So my url will be something like

http://myrestservice/country/US

so when a request come with valid country, my rest service will prepare information for that country and prepare  object called `countryInfo` and return this as

```
return  ResponseEntity.status(200).body(countryInfo);
```

now say user send request as
http://myrestservice/country/XX. In this case since XX is not valid country i have send response. I read in different place and most of them only explain about status code. My question is what is the best way to return error.

1. `return  ResponseEntity.status(404).body("Invalid Country");`
2. `return  ResponseEntity.status(404).body(myobject);` //here myObject will be `null`.
3. Prepare a Class say `MyResponse.java` as below.

   ```
   public class MyResponse {

     private String errorCode;
     private String errorDescription;
     private CountryInfo countryInfo 

   }
   ```

And return this object no matter if there are  error or not. If there is error set `errorCode` and `errorDescription` field with proper value  and set `countryInfo` to null and for no error set `errorCode` and `errorDescription` as empty and `countryInfo` with data.

Which of the above option is considered standard way to handle error.

Comment: How did you solve this? I like your 3rd approach.

Answer (score 3):

You should indeed return a 404, but what you return in the body depends on you.

Some people just return a html response with some human-readable information, but if you want your API client to get some more information about why the 404 happened, you might also want to return JSON.

Instead of using your own format, you should use the standard `application/problem+json`. It's a very simple format:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807

Comment: If my response body is not consistent all the time then on client side if they are using something like `ResponseEntity<CountryInfo> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(request, responseType);` , it will not work. I am trying to create a rest service so client has to do minimal work .

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@ControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions:

Your endpoint needs to identify the error and throw an error:

```
@RequestMapping("/country/{code}")
public ResponseEntity<Country> findCountry(String code) {
  Country country = this.countryRepository(code);
  if(country == null) throws new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid country code: " + code);
  return  ResponseEntity.status(200).body(country);
}
```

Then you create a class that will handle the exceptions of your endpoints:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { IllegalArgumentException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, 
          new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }
}
```

There you have to define the status code to indicate user what kind of error was generated, 409 in order to indicate there was a conflict.

Also, there you can define a body including further information, either a string or a custom object containing an error message and description you offer to the client thru documentation.

Comment: I want to create a standard format for response so consumer of my rest api doesn't need to do Exception handling. It might not be exception all the time. If we don't have records we have to return status saying no records found.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Zalando Problem, a library that implements application/problem+json.

https://github.com/zalando/problem

https://thecodingduck.blogspot.com/2023/01/best-practices-for-rest-api-design.html#standard_error